# Header not appearing & Footer not correct

Tags: codeigniter

I'm following the instructions in the CodeIgniter Tutorial on the Static Page but the Header does not appear although the tab is labelled "CodeIgniter Tutorial" and the content of the Footer appears on the same line as the content of the Page.

This is the content of my Pages.php - application/controllers/Pages.php

```
<?php
 class Pages extends CI_Controller
 {
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
            }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
 }
```

This is the content of my header.php - application/views/templates/header.php

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>CodeIgniter Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>

            <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
```

This is the content of my footer.php - application/views/templates/footer.php

```
            <em>&copy; 2014</em>
    </body>
 </html>
```

This is the content of my routes.php - application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

This is one URL http://localhost/MyProject/index.php/pages/view

And this is the result;

**Home**

Hello World! © *2014*

And this is the other URL http://localhost/MyProject/index.php/pages/view/about

And this is the result;

**About**

Hello World! © *2014*

I've checked every page numerous times, tried re-booting, and tried another browser, and tried CodeIgniter Forum, all to no avail.

Can somebody explain where I'm going wrong?

---

Edited

In the header.php file I've changed

```
<h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
```

to

```
<h3><?php echo $title ?></h3>
```

which makes the word "Home" decreases in size. The only file I can find the word "home" is Pages.php

```
public function view($page = 'home')
```

If I change that word to "CodeIgniter Tutorial" I get a 404 error.

The IE tab is labelled "CodeIgniter Tutorial"

I'm unsure if my expectations are correct, but this is the result that I'm expecting (but with "© 2014" at the bottom of the page);

### CodeIgniter Tutorial

Hello World!

© *2014*

Comment: weird.. it should all work. do you have Teamviewer? maybe I can take a look

Comment: Thanks CodeGodie. By you saying "it should all work" means that there is not some stupid mistake on my part.
Sorry, I don't have "Teamviewer". If you tell me where you want to look I could possibly find the error.

Comment: Maybe you can zip your whole application and upload it somewhere. I don't think the problem is with the code you're showing. Possibly some path error or similar. Check `/application/logs` and read any logs. If it's empty, make sure it's writable and set `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` in your config file.

Comment: @user225359 I updated my answer its just to do with code styling on view your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the files `views/pages/about.php` and `views/pages/home.php` are empty. Try writing something in them, for example:

**views/pages/about.php**

```
<i>This is the About page</i>
```

If the file exist, but is empty, you should get the result you're seeing, because this line will not render anything:

```
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
```

If the files don't exist, you should get some 404 output - so that's a bit weird. It could happen if the file `application/errors/error_404.php` is empty.

Comment: Thanks André Laszlo. No, the about.php and home.php pages are not empty. The contents are "Hello World!". I've tried deleting that content but the result is the same but without the words "Hello World!".

I'll edit the question to indicate the results I'm expecting.

I cannot find application/errors/error_404.php as there is no application/errors/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your project on my localhost and your pages controller is fine.

It just seems to be you need to either use p tags or div etc and then
use css style sheets etc.

**But instead of**

```
<em>&copy; 2014</em>

</body>
</html>
```

**Try**

```
<p>&copy; 2014</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Proof

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks wolfgang1983. Those files do have data so I tried the lower but the result was that the data disappeared, leaving only "Hello World!", so I reverted back to the way it was. I thought the words "NULL" and "TRUE" are used for a database. I'm currently working on the first part of the CodeIgniter Tutorial - Static Pages. The next part deals with a database. I do want to get the first part to work before I move on.

I note you are a Kiwi, I'm from Christchurch but not there at this time.

Comment: @user225359 Not sure if you have read the views user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?highlight=views

Answer (score 0):

I created a file at application/views/pages/CodeIgniter Tutorial.php

and changed

```
public function view($page = 'home')
```

to

```
public function view($page = 'CodeIgniter Tutorial')
```

in Pages.php

and changed

```
<em>&copy; 2014</em>
```

to

```
<p><br><br><em>&copy; 2014</em></br></br></p>
```

in footer.php

I can achieve close to my expectations and now realise my expectations were far too much for a simple piece of coding.